# iPad simulator iOS6, not getting image from UIImagePickerController photo library

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios6, uiimagepickercontroller

I just developed an app with new iOS6. My Xcode version is 4.5.1.  I have some issues selecting an image from `UIImagePickerController`. When I select an image, I get the following error and do not get an image on imageView

> `Could not create PLImageTable for format 4031 at path
>   /Users/mymacname/Library/Application Support/iPhone
>   Simulator/6.0/Media/PhotoData/Thumbnails/120x120.ithmb: No such file
>   or directory (2)`

It is working in iPhone5 with iOS6 but issue in iPad only.

Answer (score 1):

I found I had to launch "Photos" in the simulator before launching your app via Xcode (you only have to do this once). Launching it initializes something that needs to be there. Also, you'll have to put some images there. Easiest way is to launch Mobile Safari in the simulator go to google images and download a few images.

Comment: #markPowell i done this i see images in imagePickerview but when i select then i not getting image on my imageviewc

Comment: I have the same problem. It only happens sometimes, not every time.